# Access python variable to other stages in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins

My python script looks like

test.py

```
a=10
b=20
c=10+20
```

My Jenkins file looks like

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage("Executing python script"){
            steps{
                sh 'python test.py'                                                     
            }
        }

    stage("Getting python variable"){
        steps{
            sh "The value of c is ${c}"
          }
    
    }
    }
}
```

How can I access the value of c in stage-2 which is present inside test.py in stage-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to preserve state between two separate shell invocations is to keep it in Jenkins. To get state (in your case value of `c`) into Jenkins you need to serialize it to the console (or a file) and then capture that output in Jenkins. In you case a simple `print(c)` in python would suffice, but if the data structure gets more complex serializing to JSON is a popular choice. Then in Jenkins do this:

```
// Define a variable outside the pipeline
def cValue
pipeline {
...
cValue = sh(script: 'python test.py', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

And then you need to deserialize that state either in Jenkins (if that's where you need to use it) or pass it to other scripts. In your case casting to `int` is all that's required, but obviously gets more complex with lists and maps and whatnot.